# Why only the first test have response?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

I'm trying to write some tests for api but the problem is the response sent from api is ok only for the first request I sent to api, after that, I get

```
No content was sent from Yii application error.
```

The problem is I can't use echo directly in my `end` function (everything is ok if i use `echo`) because if the response is too long it will be flushed! and now I'm trying to use

```
Yii::$app->response;
```

and try to set my response in

```
$response->content
```

but in

```
Yii2::doRequest //the ob_get_clean()
```

function returns null after first request and throw the `No content` exception.

Any idea of how I can fix the problem with codeception?

Comment: Show us your PHP code, it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi @Vahid, the Yii2 module for codeception checks if data was sent by checking the output buffer and comparing it with the response object.
If it finds that the response has content or a stream set, but no data was output it throws this error.

The idea here is that we explicitly identify cases that are very likely to be bugs in your application. Could you show us how you set your response content?